# Search function with use of "<" and ">" in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form prompt user to enter price and system could search sth based on this price. However, instead of enter a fix number, I'd like user to enter sth like "<100" and the system could find out all the records with price less than 100.

So far I can only find the record with fix price with the following code. Can anyone help me to achieve the advanced searching?

my form:

```
<form  action = "searchs.php" method='POST' style="align:center; margin-left:530px">
   Price: <input type='text' name='searchPrice' placeholder="Type in price..." />
   <input type='submit' value='Search'>
 </form>
```

my searchs.php:

```
mysql_connect("localhost","name","1234");
    mysql_select_db("database");

    $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim($_POST['searchPrice']));

    $find= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hotel` WHERE `price` LIKE    '%$search%'");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($find))
    {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $price = $row['price'];
        $location = $row['location'];
        echo "Matched Record: $name at $location with $price dollar<br />";
    }
```

Comment: You store your price as a string? I'd change that! Anyway this is way too broad for SO; people aren't going to do your work for you.

Comment: You need to write a function in PHP code that would parse the $search variable for the conditional expressions you desire and return a query dynamically based on the user input. Basically, returning a custom SQL statement based on the user input.

Comment: store price as int: `SELECT * FROM hotel WHERE price <= 100`

Comment: You could simply have a drop-down before the input box which asks 'lesser than', 'greater than', 'lesser than or equal to' etc. and substitute the selected option accordingly. I don't feel it's a great idea to allow `<` `>` `>=` etc. into the textbox.

Comment: What happens if they put SQL in the search box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$search = trim($_POST['searchPrice']);

$operator = 'LIKE';

if (substr($search,0,1) == '<') {
  $operator = '<';
  $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(substr($search,1));
}
elseif (substr($search,0,1) == '>') {
  $operator = '>';
  $search = mysql_real_escape_string(trim(substr($search,1));
}
else {
$search = "'%".mysql_real_escape_string(trim(substr($search,1))."%'";
}

$find= mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `hotel` WHERE `price` ".$operator." " . $search);
```